# Python pre-commit fails but does not make corrections

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, githooks, pre-commit.com

I'm using some pre-commit hooks and running into an error with `python-import-sorter`. I'm getting the error below:

```
hookid: python-import-sorter

Files were modified by this hook. Additional output:

ERROR: /app/tests/standalone_regression/build_test_data.py Imports are incorrectly sorted.
Fixing /app/tests/standalone_regression/build_test_data.py
FIXED: /app/tests/standalone_regression/build_test_data.py
```

Normally it's no problem, and it reorders the imports as it sees fit. I see the changes with `git diff` or `git status`, stage the files with `git add -u` and the next `git commit` succeeds. The problem is that now I am getting nothing new to stage, so I can't commit any changes and the commit hook fails every time. How do I resolve this beyond skipping the hooks with `git commit -n`.

Relevant import section:

```
import datetime
import itertools
import json
import os
import re
from typing import Iterable, Mapping, Union

from dateutil import parser as date_parser
from pymysql import Connection

from foobar.app.app_helpers import jsonize
from foobar.db import db_utils, foo
from foobar.generators.generate_foo_file import format_file_id
from foobar.parsers import (abc_record, def_record, parse_abc_file, parse_def_file,
                              parse_ghi_file)
from foobar.parsers.parse_abc_file import validate_abc
```

Comment: can you show the full output of a `git commit` -- I suspect you have two different hooks which have differing opinions about how something should be formatted

Comment: Exactly what Anthony said. This is exactly what I'm experiencing right now. For me the `black` and `isort` seem to be stepping over each other. I'm using isort 5+ with the new configuration option of `profile=black` and that is still causing interoperability issues.

Comment: Turns out my issue was caused by incorrectly naming the `isort` config file as `isort.cfg`. I had to rename it to `.isort.cfg` (notice leading period). Once I did that, my issue with `isort` and `black` resolved and the `profile=black` setting is working as expected.